# mustache js syntax to call a function with parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, handlebars.js, mustache

I am using Mustache.js to create a template html and show set of tables.
I want to call a function inside this template with a parameter.

Every table generated from through mustache template is having a button on top of it.
I want to write a onclick function for this button.So I need the table name when processing the event.

Can someone give me the correct syntax to pass parameter?

```
<script id="TableTemplate" type="x-tmpl-mustache">
{{#tableDetails}}
<button type="button" id=Edit_{{tableName}} onclick="editTable({{tableName}})">
{{#tableDetails}}
</script>

function editTable(tableName){
    console.log("tableName >>>"+tableName)
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: This is wrong. Don't create inline event handlers, ever. Use jQuery (or some equivalent) for event handing. (Given your example it looks like you should check out an MVVM framework like knockout, which does templating *and* event handling)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it almost right. Just add the quotes.

```
onclick="editTable('{{tableName}}')"
```

Comment: Thanks Tom, What will be the problem if we do create inline event handlers?